# why list is not work properly in this code?

Tags: python

**My Code**:

```
b=list(input("entr"))

print(b)
for a in b :

    if a>5:
        print(a)
```

I got this error :

> TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Comment: input takes a string. you converted that into a list, but each item in the list is still a string.

Comment: What is your expected input and output?

Comment: Because you are trying to compare string with int

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
b=list(map(int,input("Enter: ").split()))
```

It will take `int` as inputs and convert into list.

**Ex:**

```
>>> b=list(map(int,input("Enter").split()))
Enter: 3 4 5 6 7
>>> for a in b :
        if a>5:
            print(a)       
6
7
```